# Getting the Web Capture Web Part to work were the Sharepoint is 64bit

Tags: sharepoint, 64-bit, web-parts

Previously our SharePoint server was 32-bit and we used the web capture web part to display a bugzilla search results page. Since we've migrated to a 64-bit server the webpart no longer works. We're running the same versions of everything, the only change was moving from a Windows Server 2003 32-bit box to a Windows Server 2003 64-bit box.

Oddly enough, the logs don't contain anything. The pages where the webparts appear are the only place that error messages appear. Here is what I have:

-Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

- Error - An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part.

The reason I suspect the 64bit vs 32bit issue is that I saw numerous posts on the subject in various forums. It would appear that I am not the only one with this issue and all the troubleshooting has lead to this conclusion.

Comment: Do you mean the Page Viewer Web Part?

Answer (score 0):

In all the times I have come across an error in changing from 64bit to 32bit, the change in the number of bits is usually a red herring and the actual cause of the failure is something else.

Check the sharepoint logs for the WebPart errors. They will help show exactly what is wrong.
Post the relevant errors if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the 'web capture web part'? If it isn't an out of the box web part that message makes perfect sense.. you'll need to install that web part.

Actually it might be something out of SharePoint 2003.. see [Web Capture in SharePoint 2007](http://dattard.blogspot.com/2007/02/sharepoint-2007-web-capture-web-part.html)